# Displaying an array of char from an object

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11

I am making a simple program that allows me to set the name of an object by sending an array of characters into a public member function which then changes a private variable called name. I then tell my class to spit the name variable out so I can see if it work correctly -- but my output comes out mostly garbled.

ie, I input

> "Apple"

and the output becomes

> "AAAAA╠╠╠╠Apple"

I notice that as I change the word, the number of repeating characters mimics the number of characters in the word - but I cannot seem to figure out where I messed up with my program. Here is my code:

*Note: code below now works as expected.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cstring>

    using namespace std;

    class Item{

         public:
    ~Item() { delete [] name; }

    char *setName(char * inputName)
    {
        name = new char[strlen(inputName)+1];

        int n = 0;
        for(n = 0; n<strlen(inputName); n++)
            name[n] = inputName[n];

        name[n] = '\0';

            return name;
    }

        private:
            char *name;
};


    int main()
    {
        char objectname[] = "Apple";

        Item Apple;
        cout << Apple.setName(objectname);

        int input;
        cin >> input; //pause program
    }
```

Comment: You never allocate memory for `name`. Also, `char name[]` should be `char* name` as `char name[]` is a zero-sized array, which is illegal in C++.

Comment: Simplify your life, use `std::string` instead.

Comment: @ThomasMathews I'm trying to avoid using the string class in this program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in my comment, you never allocate memory for `name`. When using `name[n]` you'll be dereference addresses that don't belong to you. This causes [Undefined Behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in your program, meaning anything can happen that doesn't conform to the logic of your program. It can even compile just fine, but you can't rely on that.

Anyway, you need to allocate memory for `name`. But for that you need to know the size of the memory to assign it to. We don't know the size of the memory (it can an arbitrary string that is sent to `setName`). Therefore `name` has to be a pointer:

```
char* name;
```

Then we can assign memory to it. BTW, `char name[]` is a zero-sized array, which is illegal in C++.

Inside `setName`, you need to get the size of the string that is sent to it. `strlen` is right for the job, but you also need to make room for the null-terminator (`'\0'`). It is the character that is appened to the end of every string, if you don't add it and try to print `name` later on, `std::cout` won't know where to stop printing each character (that's also Undefined Behavior).

Inside `setName`, this should be the assignment of the dynamic memory to `name`:

```
name = new char[strlen(inputName) + 1];
```

meaning: (number of characters in `inputName` + the null terminator). Note: `strlen` doesn't count the null-terminator.

Now, to set the null-terminator, you simply do this below the `for()` loop:

```
name[n] = '\0';
```

Moreover, when you are finished using the memory in `name`, you have to delete it. You do that using `delete[]`:

```
delete[] name;
```

---

The recommended alternative is to use `std::string` the standard C++ string class that manages memory by itself.

Comment: Thank you! I'm starting to get results - I've updated the program but am still getting errors. Not sure where I'm messing up...

Comment: @Durgal Can you share a link to the updated code [here](http://ideone.com). Also, tell me what the error is too please.

Comment: @Durgal The `x was not declared in this scope` message usually means that the compiler can't find a declaration of the name `x`. In this case, we know that `strlen` is a standard C function, so the usual explanation is that you haven't included the appropriate file to use that function. When I look up the documentation for `strlen`, I see that it is defined in the header `<cstring>`. So all you need is to do `#include <cstring>` in your program.

Comment: Here is a link: http://ideone.com/eYW6E6
The output is "AAAAA" - it's the correct number of characters, but I'm not sure why it isn't cycling through the rest of the word.

Comment: @0x499062D2 I just updated the code on ideone.com to add <cstring>

Comment: @Durgal The line `name[n] = *inputName;` is assigning each character of the `name` string to `*inputName`. What is `*inputName`? Well, since `inputName` is a pointer to the first element in the string, `*inputName` is the first character. That's what's causing the problem. You have to access the elements of the string as well by doing `name[n] = inputName[n]`.

Comment: @0x499062D2 Thank you! Just got it working - the one last issue I had was that setName() needed to be *setName().

Comment: @Durgal I'm not sure what you mean by `setName()` needed to be `*setName()`? `setName()` doesn't return something that can be dereferenced with `*`. Can you show me the code where you did that?

Comment: I ended up squishing get and set functions, that's why I needed to dereference the function. Just updated the code above.

Comment: @Durgal When I said to do `delete[] name;` when you were finished using `name`, I meant you have to `delete` it when its use is entirely fullfilled. In your code, you deleted `name` when the function ended, but you still the memory `name` later on. It's good practice to delete data members which require deallocation inside e class's destructor. Like this: `~Item() { delete[] name; }`. Search SO for The Rule of Three for a detailed explanation on this.

Comment: Also, if you don't mind, could you accept my answer by clicking on the checkmark next to it?